# Soa web-testing automate

Tags: web-services, testing, automated-tests, soapui, soa

I'm a student in 3rd year of my informatics degree. I'm trainee for 5 months and I have to automate the web-service of my company.
They are using SOA architecture.

My question is : 
To automate the test of their Web Services Soap and Rest I would like use SoapUi and Jenkins.

Someone can told me if it's the good way ? 
Can you give me a little exemple ? I'm googled my problem but i found many result different.

It help me a lot to understand what I have to do. My instructions are not clear..
Thanks a lot

Comment: SoapUI is a widely used testing tool and I particularly use it for testing my SOA. It checks out ;). Usually SoapUi just kicks off a webservices operation based on a starting message, your SOA (e.g. BPEL) will pick the message of a que and your service will be tested. This is automated in the sense that you can link many of such operations together and kick em all off simultaneously. Good luck Lucas!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have a "delivery pipeline". A set of tools, that help you build, deploy and test the application in a continuous chain of tools, that potentially can automate the entire process. Even all the way into production.

It sounds like they have already chosen Jenkins for building the application. I'm not sure if Jenkins also is doing deployment, or if there is another tool for that...? But after deployment, you should be able to start some testsuite done in SoapUI, that automatically tests the webservices, and produces a test report, that may in turn be used as a gate, deciding wether or not the application is ready to be moved further down the delivery pipeline.

So first off, you will need to get SoapUI up and running. You should find out, if you should be using the free version (SoapUI) or the licensed version (ReadyAPI).
Once you've got it installed, you should start working on a testsuite. For starters, you should just make a rudimentary testsuite that does "some testing" of the webservices. You could consider it a smoketest, simply hitting each serviceoperation once, to make sure it is up and running. Then later on, you can always build on that.

Then you will need to go into Jenkins. I suspect Jenkins can do some sort of commandline execution of third party software. (My experience with Jenkins is very limited.)
That would be SoapUI. You will need to have SoapUI installed in order to do this. The simple setup would be that you have just one machine running Jenkins. If you have a setup with several machines running Jenkins, you will have to install SoapUI on each and every one of them, that are supposed to run your SoapUI testsuite. And if you are using the licensed version of SoapUI (ReadyAPI), and you even use DataSources and other license-only functionality, you will have to look into if you should install seat licenses on every machine, or if there is a floating licence. Maybe it's all there already ready to be used. In that case, it's at least that much easier.

To reiterate: You will be aiming at a testing solution, that can be run right after build- and deploy-process is finished. Ideally the test will be so thorough, that if everything passes, you are ready to push it into production. (But actually doing that may be easier said than done, and may or may not require others to be ready for deployment too. But that doesn't mean you shouldn't be aiming for it.)